# Inserting record to Postgres schema using GO and Upper.IO

Tags: postgresql, go

I've got a postgres table whose fully qualified name is schema_name.table_name. I want to append to insert a row to table_name.

When I try

```
 tableCollection, err := db.Collection("schema_name.table_name")
```

I get a "Collection does not exist." error

If I change it to

```
tableCollection, err := db.Collection("table_name")
```

and then try

```
_,err =tableCollection.Append(myStruct)
```

I get an error "pq: relation \"table_name\" does not exist"

So it seems that UpperIO doesn't like the schema name and postgres needs to have it. Is this a bug or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Hi Airomega, I think the error is right, are you sure that the table exist exist in your pq database ?

Can you do `db.Collections()` and print the response ? 
`// Collections() returns the names of all non-system sources or tables within the active database.` [doc for this function](https://godoc.org/upper.io/db#Database)

Comment: I think your onto something however I'm still confused...

In my main.go I basically run a SELECT(*) function and the the insert function. The SELECT(*) executes raw SQL using .Query(string). It works.

However the dbCollections is returning blank. This seems to say that I'm connecting to the db to view but not when inserting.

Output:
    result len: [{1 test address true}] // raw sql Select
    Collection list: [] //db.Collections()

Comment: Full select statement is SELECT * FROM schema.table - this works. It's as if UpperIO needs the schema context too to get it working. Is there any way to do that?